# Automating downloading of a file and uploading to google sheets

Tags: email, google-sheets, automation

I receive CSV files via a link (not attachment) in my email, I'm looking for a solution that would automate the process of downloading these links and turning around and uploading them to google sheets.

So far I've tried some solutions involving Keyboard Maestro and Zapier, but can't quite figure it out. Is there an obvious tool for this kind of automation that I'm missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please think of this as one of several workarounds. If you can receive the email at Gmail, for example, how about using Google Apps Script? When you use it, you can put the values by retrieving the CSV values from the URL. In this case, the trigger is the time-driven trigger.

Comment: This approach sounds great, however it appears to be that link isn't actually a .csv file but some script that causes a CSV file to download...

Comment: Thank you for replying. The link you have is not a direct link of CSV file? I cannot understand about it. I'm sorry.